# es6 javascript class with pub sub pattern, losing context

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, publish-subscribe, babeljs, es6-class

i'm kinda new to es6 features, i'm trying to implement some basic class, like this

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    console.log("init!");
    this.hello();
  }

  hello(){
    console.log("Hello!");
  }
}

let app = new App;
```

everything works fine. this is my output:

```
init
Hello!
```

then i tried to implement the same thing with publish / subscribe pattern (using [PubSubJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js) plugin):

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    PubSub.subscribe('say hello', this.init);
  }

  init() {
    console.log("init!");
    this.hello();
  }

  hello(){
    console.log("Hello!");
  }
}

let app = new App;

PubSub.publish('say hello');
```

This will call correctly the `init` method, but then will lose the class context when trying to call `this.hello()`

infact i get this output:

```
init //correct
Uncaught TypeError: this.hello is not a function //<- why this?
```

[DEMO HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpYmrQ?editors=0012)

any idea? am i missing something? thanks

Comment: You're passing down a method without the class necessarily having been instantiated. [Code pen with fixed version.][1]. Some useful articles to help understand `this` in JS:

 - http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work


  [1]: https://codepen.io/nowy5/pen/NBKwGR?editors=0011
  [2]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
  [3]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: thanks @nowy it works now :)